# Custom RelativeLayout to have circular boundary

Tags: android, user-interface, android-relativelayout

I have a requirement to show a View which need to have a circular boundary.
I know it can be done by Extending the RelativeLayout. But exactly dont know what all methods to override except constructors and what code changes I have to make for it to show circular boundary.

Updated question with Image.
So basically this is an animation.
and minutely the view goes out from screen from the circumference of the circle (And not as rectangular view).
So I have to create a circular view (Relative Layout) that is having child of these images.
[image: Image which have circular corner view]

Comment: Could you provide some image or further explanation to help understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: i think you should use circular imageview.

Comment: Circular imageView wont give the child a circumference area. Rather the child will have rectangular area.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android.support.v7.cardview` and put a `RelativeLayout` as its child.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html

Note from the above link:

> Due to expensive nature of rounded corner clipping, on platforms
>   before L, CardView does not clip its children that intersect with
>   rounded corners. Instead, it adds padding to avoid such intersection
>   (See setPreventCornerOverlap(boolean) to change this behavior).

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to make any layout with rounded border. using below code for make layout rounded.

round.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item><shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/list_row_bg" />
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" 
            android:bottomRightRadius="4dp" 
            android:topLeftRadius="4dp" 
            android:topRightRadius="4dp" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/header_bg" />
    </shape></item>
 </selector>
```

put this round.xml file drawable folder. and use as backgournd in your layout.

my_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="25dp" >

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Elesh. My point is the view will look as circle. But the boundary will not be rounded. And the animation view will pass as from rectangular corner of parent view not the circumference of circular view.